# SoapUI: Using Run TestCase test step doesn't pass in context

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm using SoapUI Pro. The SoapUI site says I should be able to set context variables and get those values at any time during the test's execution. In the help it says:

> A common usage scenario is for looping or keeping track of progress by saving the corresponding counters and collections to the context and using them to control flow as required.

I can't get this to work if I'm using the out-of-the-box 'Run TestCase' test step. The called test doesn't seem to get passed the context information.

Here's a very basic example. In my originating test I put in some Groovy script that says this:

`context.PassedInTest = "Is this passed in?" log.info(context.PassedInTest)`

Then in my called test, I have another Groovy script that says this:

`log.info(context.PassedInTest)`

Upon execution of the test, the log displays: `"Is this passed in?"` for the originating test, but then the log displays `null` for the called test:

```
Mon Oct 27 12:59:45 EDT 2014:INFO:Is this passed in?
Mon Oct 27 12:59:56 EDT 2014:INFO:null
```

Is there a way to pass in the context if using the out-of-the-box 'Run TestCase' test step in SoapUI (i.e. not using Groovy script)? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Each test case has a different `context`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working, but I can't say if it's hacky or not...

Consider following project structure:

```
Project
|-CallingTestSuite
| |-CallingTestCase
|   |-TestSteps
|     |-LocalScript (Groovy TestStep)
|     |-RemoteScript (Run TestCase TestStep)
|-CalledTestsuite
  |-CalledTestCase
    |-TestSteps
      |-CalledScript (Groovy TestStep)
```

Now, you cannot pass (at least I didn't find a way) context of LocalScript to CalledScript.
You can, however, access the content of LocalScript from CalledScript.

LocalScript:

```
context.PassedInTest = "Is this passed in?"
log.info(context.PassedInTest)
```

CalledScript:

```
if (context.getProperty("#CallingTestRunContext#") != null){
    log.info(context.getProperty("#CallingTestRunContext#").PassedInTest);
}
```

Keep in mind that it needs to be executed as CallingTestSuite, CallingTestCase, or Project, otherwise the target context won't be available.